# Magento 2.3 : Category names missing from breadcrumbs on the product page

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, breadcrumbs

I am using Magento 2.3 for my store.On the product page category and subcategory are missing from the breadcrumb.Is there any workaround to show the fullpath with category and subcategories in the breadcrumb on the product detail page?

It now only shows: `Home > Current Product Name`

Any help?

Thanks in advance.!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add to the `view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file of your module or theme:

```xml
<referenceBlock name='breadcrumbs' template='Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml' />
<block class='Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VedoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml" />
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs" />
    </body>
</page>
```